# Как в Team Foundation Server настроить автоматическую компиляцию и перезапуск сервера при заливке информации на Team Foundation Server?

Tags: asp.net-core, visual-studio-2017, непрерывная-интеграция

Есть мой веб сервер Asp.Net Core и на этом же компе стоит Team Foundation Server.
Есть удалённый комп, где я разрабатываю.
Я хочу, что б компилировался мой проект и запускалась новая его версия, когда я их солью на Team Foundation Server (либо при отправке команды - перекомпилировать и запустить).
Вообщем подсказали непрерывную интеграцию, но я так и не понял- как это реализовать ?